# Jaspersoft Studio Variable in Chart Expression

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports

I am afraid I am overthinking this but I am having issues using a variable in my pie chart "increment expression".

All I want is this: $F{dataAsOfDate}==$V{maxDate} but it doesn't work. Instead it still pulls in all the records as if this filter is not in place. The only thing I can think of is that it is evaluating the variable on every row. There are a total of 12 dates in the datasource and I am only wanting the pie chart to use data for the most recent date.

I am only using the summary band with a pie chart and one other column/line combo chart. The pie chart has a reset type of "Report" and an increment type of "None".

Version: Jaspersoft Studio Professional 6.1

Datasource: CSV file

maxDate variable: Calculation is "Highest" of the dataAsOfDate values. Increment type is "Report" and a Reset type of "None"

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the **Main dataset** by the below expression in the **Filter expression**

```
$F{dataAsOfDate}.contains($V{maxDate}) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

Hope this should solve your question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback viki! Unfortunately, I am not looking to filter at the Main dataset but only inside the chart. Also, I was unable to get that code to work either. It seems strange to me that this is such a difficult task. If the variable is set to initialize at the beginning of the report why can't I just say that I only want data where it matches the variable?